# executor.map() TypeError: zip argument #2 must support iteration

Tags: python, python-3.x

executor.map()    TypeError: zip argument #2 must support iteration

when I run it ,just generated TypeError: zip argument #2 must support iteration.
can anyone help me fix this problem ?

```
import time, concurrent.futures
lst100=[i for i in range(100)]

t1=time.clock()
print(list(map(str,lst100)))
t2=time.clock()
print(t2-t1)

t3=time.clock()
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=100) as executor:
    future_to_url = executor.map(str,lst100, 60)
    print(list(future_to_url))
t4=time.clock()
print(t4-t3)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`concurrent.futures.Executor.map`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Executor.map) is semantically identical to the built-in function [`map`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map).  The second and subsequent *non-keyword* arguments specify the iterables to apply the given function to.

In your case, you're saying "Here are two iterables: a list of 100 elements (`lst100`) and the integer 60.  Please call the function `str()` on each pair of elements `a` and `b` coming form the two iterables respectively, and return the list of results."  But since the integer 60 is not actually an iterable object, it fails.

Assuming you wanted to specify a timeout of 60 seconds, you need to pass it as a keyword argument like so:

```
future_to_url = executor.map(str, lst100, timeout=60)
```

Keyword arguments are distinguished from positional arguments by the presence of the `name=` prefix before the value being passed.  In this case, the argument name is `timeout`.